# Disable Wordpress password hashing

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

my users come to my wordpress website from another system. This system is sending $_SESSION to my Wordpress.

I have function how to make login automatically. But problem is, that i can take just hashed password from my DB. I need to disable password hashing and my function will work.

```
    function wpdocs_custom_login() {

        if(isset($_SESSION['usr_email'])){
            $user = get_user_by( 'login', $_SESSION['usr_login'] );

            $creds = array(
                'user_login'    => $user->user_login,
                'user_password' => $user->user_pass,
                'remember'      => true
            );

            $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

            if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
                echo $user->get_error_message();
            }
        }

}

// Run before the headers and cookies are sent.
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_custom_login' );
?>
```

Can you help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should be authenticating people if they should be logged in due to being logged in in some 3rd party system.

```
$user = get_user_by('login', $_SESSION['usr_login']);
if($user)
{
    clean_user_cache($user->ID);
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    if (wp_validate_auth_cookie() == FALSE)
    {
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
    }
}
```

This way you can log them in without compromising security.
Relevant docs:
[clean_user_cache](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/clean_user_cache/)
[wp_set_current_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_current_user/)
[wp_validate_auth_cookie](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_auth_cookie/)
[wp_clear_auth_cookie](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_clear_auth_cookie/)
[wp_set_auth_cookie](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_auth_cookie/)